# C++ linear access to 3 dimensional array

Tags: c++, arrays, indexing

Hello as far as I understand when I allocate 3 dimensional array I truly get linear memory that is just interpreted as 3 dimensional by defining stride.

So I want to access using linear index the 3 dimensional array, but  how can I get first element using linear index - it should be possible in principle for example given int32 in order to get 11th element I should move 320 bits from beginin f the array take next 32 and interpret those bits as int - seems to be far more performant than calculate the 3 d indicies from linear index as it would require multiple divisions...

Below I tried dereferncing but still I do it incorrectly as I am here as far as I get get dereferncing to 0th element of second array not what I intend to

C++ code

```
int intsss[3][3][3] = {
                     { {1,2, 3}, {4, 5, 6}, {7,8, 9} },
                     { {10,11, 12}, {13, 14, 15}, {16,17, 18} },
                     { {19,20, 21}, {22, 23, 24}, {25,26, 27} }
  };

 std::cout << intsss[0][0][1] << std::endl;
  std::cout << **intsss[1] << std::endl;
```

output

```
2
10
```

Comment: `intsss[0]` is an array, and arrays decay to pointers. You're looking at an address.

Comment: Ok I get It ! so how to get first element using linear index !

Comment: just dereference the pointer `*intsss[0]`

Comment: Thanks, I updated question, how do you exactly consider dereferencing for this particular 3d case? I am doing still sth wrong as visible above

Comment: `*intsss[0] + index_1D`, but I think that's ugly AF, and technically Undefined Behaviour (UB) if you traverse past the size of the inner-most array. You could also use a `union` to type-pun (also UB) a 1D array in the same space as the 3D array or use a `reinterpret_cast` to tell the compiler to use `intsss` as a pointer to `int` (still UB). I strongly recommend doing some profiling indexing the the 3D array normally to see if it really is a problem once the optimizer's done with your code.

Comment: In the past I've had pretty good success making 1D arrays and wrapping them in a class that makes them look multidimensional to outsiders by performing all of the indexing math myself. Normally I do this when I have a variable-sized or variable-dimensioned structure, but the same could apply here without breaking any language laws.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`**intsss[1]` is the same as `**(intsss[1])`. If you want to express `intsss[0][0][1]` in a different way, use `(**intsss)[1]` (but in my opinion, it's pointless).

To address your multidimensional array in a linear way, first get a pointer to the first element: `&intsss[0][0][0]`. Then use it like a normal pointer:

```
int* p = &intsss[0][0][0];
std::cout << p[1];
```

There are a few other equivalent ways to get a pointer to the first element: `intsss[0][0]` or `**intsss`. If you use these, you should be careful and make sure you understand how exactly pointer decay works, and make sure you get a pointer to `int` and not a pointer to an array. For example: `intsss[0]` is a 2-D array, which decays to a pointer to an array of 3 ints. Doing arithmetic on this pointer jumps 3 ints at once — probably not what you want.

Strictly speaking, such linear addressing is illegal (undefined behaviour) if you go past the end of the innermost array. But in practice, it works.

Answer (score 0):

Use below code to play-around till u get what you want.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
#include <string>

void PRINT(const std::string &s) { std::cout << s; std::cout.flush(); }
template<typename...T> void say(T...t) { std::string s{}; std::stringstream ss(""); (ss<<...<<t); s=ss.str(); PRINT(s); }

int main()
{
    int intsss[3][3][3] = { { {1,2, 3}, {4, 5, 6}, {7,8, 9} },
                            { {10,11, 12}, {13, 14, 15}, {16,17, 18} },
                            { {19,20, 21}, {22, 23, 24}, {25,26, 27} } };
    int a, b, c;
    say("\n-----------\n");
    a=intsss[2][2][0];
    b=intsss[2][2][1];
    c=intsss[2][2][2];
    say("330 -> ", a, "\n331 -> ", b, "\n332 -> ", c, "\n");
    
    say("\n-----------\n");
    a=**intsss[0];
    b=**intsss[1];
    c=**intsss[2];
    say("**0 -> ", a, "\n**1 -> ", b, "\n**2 -> ", c, "\n");
    
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You will need to provide some more details first..

Comment: @tilz0R: "give a beggar a fish... or teach a beggar how to fish..."